# Fourier Transform of Density Operator boosting momentum

Tags: condensed-matter, momentum, fourier-transform, density-operator, correlation-functions

I am currently reading Girvin and Yang's book on Condensed Matter Physics. I am reading up on the dynamical structure factor and in Section 4.3 where they talk about how $\rho_{+q}$, which is defined as the fourier transform of the density operator, "boost(s) the momentum of one of the particles by $-\hbar\vec{q}$". I don't see this. How are they reaching this conclusion? The relevant definitions are as follows:

$$\hat{\rho}_{q}=\int d^3\vec{r} \, exp(-i \vec{q}.\vec{r})\hat{\rho}(\vec{r},t)$$

with $$\hat{\rho}(\vec{r},t)=\sum_{j=1}^N \delta^3(\hat{r}-r_j)$$